# Pronuncing "th" and "c" when they are back to back as in "health center"

Tags: pronunciation

For example, I feel it hard to pronounce "health center" as it gets stuck when I'm switching from "th" to "s". What's the correct way to pronounce it?

Answer (score 6):

Pronounce both the [θ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_fricative) and [s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolar_sibilant) sounds in sequence:

1. To pronounce θ, place the tip of your tongue just under your upper teeth and breathe out.  Your vocal cords should not vibrate; this sound is [*voiceless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_consonant).
2. To pronounce s, continue breathing out; pull your tongue back in a smooth movement, until the tip of your tongue is on the ridge behind the upper teeth.  This sound is also voiceless.

Practice this tongue movement slowly until it is natural.